# Ubuntu PID process ID

Tags: ubuntu

I want to know how to find out my PID processing ID. However when I try to do this it says:

```
cat: /proc/PID/status: No such file or directory
```

The command I tried is:

```
cat /proc/PID/status
```

Answer (score 3):

In most shells and in Perl, your current pid is in the variable `$$`:

```
$ echo $$
14886
$

$ perl -e 'print "$$\n"'
15006
$
```

Answer (score 2):

In `/proc/PID/status`, PID is a placeholder for an actual process ID. You can't just call `cat /proc/PID/status` because that doesn't exist.

If you want to find out a process ID, just use

```
ps -ef | grep -i "process name" | grep -v grep
```

The PID will be the second column, the third column is the parent process ID.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the **top** command on a terminal for output like this:

---

top - 11:09:20 up 9 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.14, 0.39, 0.39
**Tasks: 178 total,   2 running, 176 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie**
Cpu(s):  2.3%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3081644k total,  1178648k used,  1902996k free,   128244k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   392340k cached

**PID** USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 2595 user      20   0 82868  21m  11m S    3  0.7   0:13.02 npviewer.bin
 1375 root      20   0  167m  15m 8400 S    2  0.5   0:13.72 Xorg
 2665 user      20   0  397m  15m  11m S    1  0.5   0:00.24 gnome-terminal
 2689 user      20   0 19276 1364  956 R    1  0.0   0:00.09 top
 2073 user      20   0  310m  33m 8568 S    0  1.1   0:05.65 compiz
 2200 user      20   0  212m  10m 8240 S    0  0.3   0:01.97 multiload-apple
 2469 user      20   0  612m  63m  32m S    0  2.1   0:17.31 chromium-browse

---

The first column of the output with the four digit numbers (in this particular output) is the process ID for the process name at the far right of the table. BTW, press 'q' to exit top or it will keep polling and updating endlessly every few seconds.

*top* only shows a screenful's worth of lines with the hungriest processes rather than the dozens of total processes. You can use **slhck**'s pattern to find other processes. Even my own example had about 200 processes running.

You probably are looking for your process ID as an intermediate step to something else. If you need to kill a process, because it's out of control, you can research **kill** and **killall**. you can type *man kill* and it will give you useful info. To exit that *man*page and most other interactive CLI programs such as top, press 'q'.